# How to change styling of something using javascript on going back in history?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, nuxt.js

In the navbar, I have used stylings for active links. Like I have About Us, Contact Us, Material, Quizzes etc. links in the navbar and when clicking on these links, the route changes i.e. 'http://localhost:3000/about-us', 'http://localhost:3000/material' etc. and subsequently the active class applies to that link so that the link is highlighted on corresponding route.

When toggling between links the active class applies correctly, but i've noticed that when going back in history (Clicking on back button in browser) like from '/material' to '/home', the active class doesn't applies. It's still applied on the same route's link (before clicking back).

I have applied active class styling to navlinks using javascript on mounted() (for checking initially the route and applying the style) as well as on clicking the links (toggling).

So what could be the reason for it not changing on going back in history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful, the classes in Nuxt are actually

- `nuxt-link-active`
- `nuxt-link-exact-active`

Here is an example: https://nuxtjs.org/examples/routing-active-links-classes

This can meanwhile be changed in the configuration as shown here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-router#linkactiveclass

Answer (score 2):

If you use `vue-router` and its `<router-link>` component, you don't have to manage this yourself :)

The component applies a special css class to the current active link. By default, the css class is `router-link-active`.

```css
<style>
/* Style the current active link */
.router-link-active {
   background-color: blue;
}
</style>
```

Documentation: https://router.vuejs.org/api/#active-class

Comment: Well, I am using NuxtJs and also I haven't done routing with <nuxt-link> instead I have done with push history method. The navlinks are actually <p> tags and in their click function (on clicking them) I have pushed history to the specified route like this.$router.push(url) where 'url' is obtained from parameters of click function. And after the push method I have applied css to navlinks with javascript. Is there any way to handle this? Or else I will have to use nuxt link (which I didn't use because it was causing some issues).

Comment: You should definitely use `<nuxt-link>` components, they do exactly what you've done manually, but they handle everything. I don't see how they can cause any issue for your app, they're just a wrapper to `<a>` or `<button>`.

Comment: I think the nuxt-link was causing styling issues. Some stylings were not applying on it. Anyways, thanks for replying.

Comment: `nuxt-link` is more than just a **wrapper** for `a` tho, because it is not doing a browser navigation but a VueJS router one, meaningful difference. Some people sometimes think that it's totally fine to use `a` tags to move into an SPA.

Comment: You're totally right Kissu :) I just wanted to mention it's a wrapper that doesn't add any dom element, it directly renders to a native anchor, just like you would do with native HTML tags. It doesn't even add css classes (except for the `nuxt-link-active`, so any style issues is likely not related to the usage of this component)